# Universal covers of two non-homeomorphic $K(G,1)$ space

Tags: algebraic-topology

I know any two $K(G,1)$ spaces are homotopic and their universal covers are contractible. I am just curious how universal covers of two $K(G,1)$ spaces are related.

Is there any general result like, when are they homeomorphic?

Comment: I don't expect you'll get anything (but I'm willing to be wrong).  All this theory throws away strict homeo data and cares only about the homotopy types.  How much extra relation do you want between two contractible spaces?  That's already pretty informative.

Comment: I think it is very difficult to come up with such a condition. For example, $M_n = S^1\times\mathbb{R}^n$ is a $K(\mathbb{Z}, 1)$ for every $n \geq 0$, but the universal covers $\widetilde{M_n} = \mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ are all distinct.

Comment: @Michael:  Or even easier, $N_n = \mathbb{R}^n$ is a $K(\{e\}, 1)$ for every $n\geq 0$, and the universal covers are distinct ;-).

Comment: @Randall Thanks a lot, I realize now how stupid the question is. The way things are defined, that information is forgotten right away.

Comment: I don't think there's such a thing as a "stupid" question about E-Mac spaces.

Comment: Generalizing some of the other comments, any contractible space with a free action of $G$ will be the universal cover of a $K(G,1)$, and a quick way to go from a contractible $G$-space to another contractible $G$ space is to take the product (and this preserves freeness as well).  Giving an arbitrary contractible space the trivial action, we see that we can take the product of our universal cover with ANY contractible space and get a different universal cover.

Comment: @Aaron Thanks! This is what I was thinking about the examples, that how the action is defined. Wouldn't trivial action non-free by definition? Where would an element of $G$ send an element of the other contractible space?

Comment: @m_ath While the trivial action is non-free, if $G$ acts on $A$ and $B$ and the action on $A$ is free, then the action on $A\times B$ will be free regardless what the action on $B$ is.  For suppose that $g\neq e$.  Then since $ga\neq a$, g(a,b)\neq (a,b)$ (just look at the first coordinate).

Comment: @Aaron Oh yeah! Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact, there is no hope for two $K(G,1)$'s being homeomorphic and similarly for their universal covers. Generally, for a topological space $G$ you could construct a universal bundle $EG \to BG$ where $BG = K(G,1)$ is a classifying space of $G$-principal bundles, means $[X,BG] = \text{Prin}_{G}(X)$ and $EG$ can be supposed to be spherical. In the category of connected CW-complex, it means $EG$ is homotopic to one point.

The universal property of this kind of bundle forces all $BG$'s to be unique up to a homotopy equivalence through a commutative diagram but no hope for $EG$'s.
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
E_{1} @>{\widetilde{h}}>> E_{2}\\
@VVV @VVV\\
B_{1} @>{h}>> B_{2}
\end{CD}